# Join Based on Best Match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these two tables:

```
Table: Estimates

| EstimateNumber | Quantity | TotalCost |
| -------------- | -------- | --------- |
| 183232         | 2000     | 5890.42   |
| 183232         | 2500     | 6935.63   |
| 183232         | 3500     | 9016.21   |
| 183232         | 3000     | 7980.28   |

Table: Jobs

| JobNumber | EstimateNumber | QuantityOrdered |
| --------- | -------------- | --------------- |
| PK05188   | 183232         | 2500            |
| PK05591   | 183232         | 3000            |
```

I would like this:

```
| Job Number | TotalCost | Other_Info_From_Corresponding_Estimates_Row |
| ---------- | --------- | ------------------------------------------ |
| PK05188    | 6935.63   | 'Example'                                  |
| PK05591    | 7980.28   | 'Example'                                  |
```

Where the correct associated cost is the one with the closest quantity. Originally I was doing something like this:

```
SELECT 

    Estimates.EstimateNumber,
    Estimates.TotalCost

FROM Estimates

INNER JOIN

    (SELECT DISTINCT

        Jobs.EstimateNumber,
        FIRST_VALUE( Estimates.Quantity ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Jobs.EstimateNumber ORDER BY ABS( Jobs.QuantityOrdered - Estimates.Quantity ) ASC ) CorrectQuantity

FROM Jobs

INNER JOIN Estimates

ON Jobs.EstimateNumber = Estimates.EstimateNumber ) AS QuantityTable

ON Estimates.EstimateNumber = QuantityTable.EstimateNumber AND Estimates.Quantity = QuantityTable.CorrectQuantity
```

Then using this as a subquery and matching the JobNumber based on the corresponding EstimateNumber. However I failed to realize that while a JobNumber is distinct, they may occasionally refer to the same estimate. This causes understandably strange behavior, where one of the jobs will 'win' the closest match based on the underlying order of operations. And even without that behavior, it would end up duplicating the Jobs when joined.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the "Estimates" table, are EstimateNumber and Quantity always unique?

Comment: EstimateNumber is not unique as shown in the given tables. Each quantity is unique for a given EstimateNumber

Answer (score 3):

For your sample data, you can use an exact match:

```
select j.*, e.*
from jobs j left join
     estimates e
     on j.jobnumber = e.jobnumber and
        j.QuantityOrdered = e.quantity;
```

However, your question suggests that there might not be an exact match.  You don't specify the rules that define "closest", but you can use a lateral join for this:

```
select j.*, e.*
from jobs j outer apply
     (select top (1) e.*
      from estimates e
      where j.jobnumber = e.jobnumber and
      order by abs(j.QuantityOrdered - e.quantity)
     ) e
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you might not always have an exact match, from your wording, the following should give you the sample output:

```
select j.JobNumber, e.*
from Jobs j
outer apply (
    select totalCost, OtherStuff from (
        select e.totalcost, e.OtherStuff, Row_Number() over(order by Abs(j.quantityordered-e.quantity)) rn
        from Estimates e
        where e.estimatenumber=j.estimatenumber
    )e where rn=1
)e
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ;with cte as(
      SELECT
        A.JobNumber,
        A.EstimateNumber,
        B.TotalCost,
        estimate_rank=row_number() over 
                      (partition by A.JobNumber,A.EstimateNumber
                       order by A.JobNumber,
                                A.EstimateNumber,ABS(A.QuantityOrdered-B.Quantity)
                             )
      FROM Jobs A
      JOIN Estimates B ON A.EstimateNumber=B.EstimateNumber
 )
 SELECT JobNumber,TotalCost
 FROM cte
 WHERE
 estimate_rank=1
```

Comment: Good answers should include an explanation in addition to the code so that the OP can learn from it.